# How to send data to a not specific sheet automatically

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro that send values to another sheet:

```
Sheets("MATRIZ DE POLIVALÊNCIA").Select
Columns("E:E").Select
Range("E4").Activate
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("E8").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='RICARDO'!R[-6]C[19]"
Range("E9").Select
Selection.FillDown
Range("E10").Select
Selection.FillDown`
```

But, doing like that, it only works specifically with the 'RICARDO' tab, I want to do it for many other sheets.

I am creating a record of every employee in the company, this record contains their skills, from 0 to 3, I want to send these skills levels to a main table, 'MATRIZ DE POLIVALÊNCIA'.

[image: I want send the skill levels from this one]

Comment: Maybe if you [edit] your post and paste some sample data pictures, it'd be easier to help you with your requirements

Comment: You would need to change the `Ricardo` part in `"='RICARDO'!R[-6]C[19]"` You could di it with a variable, like `"='" & MyVar & "'!R[-6]C[19]"`. Also, you may benefit from [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/9199828)

Comment: my sheet name is in V2, how can i get it in a variable? im a beginner

Comment: i think i did it